# Calling a function on user complete enter the text

Tags: angular, autocomplete

I'm purposely to implementing an auto-complete dropdown using [ng2-autocomplete](https://github.com/oferh/ng2-completer). But my data source is on remote and I query the data source using a server in my Angular 2 service application.

## Component View

```
<ng2-completer 
      [(ngModel)]="searchStr" 
      [datasource]="dataService" 
      [minSearchLength]="0"  
      (change)='findAddress($event)'>
</ng2-completer>
```

## Component

```
findAddress($event){
      this.addressCrawlerService.findMap($event.target.value)
          .subscribe(
              res => {
                  let resultArray = res["result"];
                  this.searchData = resultArray;
                  this.dataService = this.completerService.local(this.searchData, 'streetAddress', 'streetAddress');
              },
              error => {
                  console.log(error.json);
              }
          ); 
}
```

Here the values are not fired when the value changed. What's wrong on my code to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to delay the service call until the user stops typing.

For that you have two options:

1. Use the Angular way like described here https://angular.io/guide/http#1-wait-for-the-user-to-stop-typing
2. Use the 'javascript' way... see this plunker example:

   https://embed.plnkr.co/9VYmoGxKO3buc4DmVQgl/

The principle for both ways is the same. For each character typed both set a timer to wait for i.e. 400 ms. If the user types the next character within the 400ms the already set timer is stopped and a new timer starts. If the 400ms go by without typing the code gets executed.

Comment: Let me know `(change)` is the proper event for this ?

Comment: Better use (keyup). I am not familiar to that component. In the source https://github.com/oferh/ng2-completer/blob/master/src/components/completer-cmp.ts I cannot find a change output parameter but the keyup.